# PHP Date Fields

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

So I have a bunch of date fields here.

The issue I have is that I need to add 2 hours to $currentdateunix.

I have to monitor a bunch of things on my page and I want to give the $monitorcheck 2 extra hours to sync up just in case.

```
 //Getting datetime field as UNIX time
 $unitdate = strtotime($us[datetime]);

//Getting current date as UNIX
$currentdateunix = strtotime(date("F j, Y, g:i a"));

//Getting current date
$currentdate = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

//Calculation for Monitor Status
$monitorcheck = ($currentdateunix - $unitdate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two hours to the current date and time:

```
$currentdateunix = strtotime('+2 hours');
```

Comment: strtotime() automatically assumes the current date in my format?

Comment: Yes. If you do not provide a date, "now" is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Add 7200 to the UNIX Timestamp? According to [this](http://www.epochconverter.com/) converter, that should do the trick.